# Image upload not moving file php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, pdo, upload

I'm trying to build an image upload on my site. The code I'm using inserts value into my database, but the image isn't moved to my directory?

Can anybody help me on this, or give me advice on how to debug this?

**Inputs**

```
 <label for="picture_1">picture 1 : </label>
    <input type="file" name="picture_1" id="picture_1" />
</li>
<li>
    <label for="picture_2">picture 2 : </label>
    <input type="file" name="picture_2" id="picture_2" />
</li>
<li>
    <label for="picture_3">picture 3 : </label>
    <input type="file" name="picture_3" id="picture_3" />
```

**File upload**

```
if(sizeof($_FILES)){ 
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
 $aFile = $_FILES['picture_'.$i];
 if(empty($aFile['tmp_name'])) continue; # skip for empty elements

    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $aFile["name"]));
    if ((($aFile["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($aFile["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($aFile["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($aFile["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($aFile["size"] < 200000000)
    && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($aFile["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " .$aFile["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {       
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $aFile["name"]))
          {
          echo $aFile["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'], 
            "upload/" .$aFile["name"]); 
          echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
          }
        }
      }
    else
    {
      echo "Invalid file";  
    }
}
```

**Complete Page**

```
include 'assets/connection.class.php';


$firstname = $_POST['First_Name'];


// Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = '';
$userdb = '';
$passdb = '';

try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $sql = "INSERT STMT WAS HERE";

 $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $statement->bindValue(":firstname", $firstname);
 ...
 List of bind values etc is here


 $count = $statement->execute();

  $conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}


if(sizeof($_FILES)){ 
    for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
     $aFile = $_FILES['picture_'.$i];
     if(empty($aFile['tmp_name'])) continue; # skip for empty elements

        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $aFile["name"]));
        if ((($aFile["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($aFile["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($aFile["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($aFile["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
        && ($aFile["size"] < 200000000)
        && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($aFile["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " .$aFile["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {       
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $aFile["name"]))
              {
              echo $aFile["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'], "'upload/" .$aFile["name"]."'"); 
              echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
              }         
            }
          }
        else
        {
          echo "Invalid file";  
        }
    }

}


// If data added ($count not false) displays the number of rows added
if($count !== false) echo 'Number of rows added: '. $count; 


?>


<a href="test.php">Go back </a>
```

**Error log**

```
[Tue Aug 13 19:27:31 2013] [error] [client 89.240.60.62] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file('upload/13-001945_1.jpg'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/liam.co.uk/domains/tiercakes.co.uk/public_html/access/add-cake.php on line 132, referer: http://www.tiercakes.co.uk/access/add-cake.php

[Tue Aug 13 19:27:31 2013] [error] [client 89.240.60.62] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpxrwtlM' to ''upload/13-001945_1.jpg'' in /home/liam.co.uk/domains/tiercakes.co.uk/public_html/access/add-cake.php on line 132, referer: http://www.tiercakes.co.uk/access/add-cake.php
```

Comment: What message do you get?

Comment: I dont get anything @BartFriederichs, I have an insert statement above this too, could that be a problem?

Comment: add some var_dumps to see in which if/else case it falls under

Comment: Also no notices in the server logs?

Comment: Can we assume you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag?

Comment: Also, have you set write permissions on the `upload/` folder?

Comment: Let me ask you how good are you with jquery and php i have got a complete uploading system that i can give you to upload multi files instead of you having more than 3 upload button. And all you will need to do is to just reference your file name to your database. let me know in few minutes

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(!empty($aFile['tmp_name'])) continue;` instead of `if(empty($aFile['tmp_name'])) continue;` since you only want to continue if the `tmp_name` is not empty?

Comment: @Liam The `{` after `&& in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts))` should probably be reversed to `}` **and** one too many closing braces after `echo "Invalid file";` deleting one ought to do the trick. Try that and let me know. I have another possible scenario for you to try.

Comment: " Probable " cause: Mismatched braces.

Comment: @Fred, this causes a syntax error in my code

Comment: @Liam It's really hard for me to tell what belongs with which function. But it is definitely the mismatched braces.

Comment: Sorry @Fred, Ive uploaded my complete php page that includes the funciton

Comment: @Liam I'll have to look at it later. It's passed 4:30 am here, I need some shuteye. See what I can do when I get back.

Comment: @Liam In the meantime, try adding a closing brace `}` at the very end of your File Upload body of code, just underneath `echo "Invalid file";` - see if that does the trick.

Comment: @Fred, Ive uploaded my error log report

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing curly brace which is creating an error in your php file and therefore it will not execute. This should be the end of your code like this:

```
    else
        {
          echo "Invalid file";  
        }
    }
}
```

Just add the last curly brace it looks like, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!, problem was this line

```
move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'], "'upload/" .$aFile["name"]."'");
```

I had an extra ' at the beginning of upload and at the end of the filename, I noticed this in the apache error log, thanks for all your input